# Prolog returning empty list, problem with base case on recursive predicate

Tags: list, recursion, prolog, predicate

So basically I am working with a list of lists that create a 100x100 grid. I am building a predicate below that takes in the grid and swaps a rows cells to all ones and returns the new board. So far all of the other predicates I have made work as intended so I will just show the problematic part:

```
generationRow(L,_,0,L).
generationRow(Board,X,Y,New) :-
    Y > 0, 
    X1 is X-1, % account for 0 indexed array
    Y1 is Y-1,
    replaceCell(Board,X1,Y1,1,NewBoard),
    generationRow(NewBoard,X,Y1,NewBoard).
```

When I execute generation row as such:
    generationRow(Board,10,100,NewBoard)
    write(Newboard).

It returns Newboard = [] which blows my mind because replacecell returns the correct array when called. Thus I think the issue must be with my base case. Based on the algorithm the base case should be when Y=0, X will never change, and board should be equal to Newboard. I thought I did that right.

Answer (score 1):

You probably made a mistake in your last call:

```
generationRow(L,_,0,L).
generationRow(Board, X, Y, New) :-
    Y > 0, 
    X1 is X-1, % account for 0 indexed array
    Y1 is Y-1,
    replaceCell(Board,X1,Y1,1, NewBoard),
    generationRow(NewBoard, X, Y1, New).
```

In the original code fragment, you made a call with `generationRow(NewBoard,X,Y1,NewBoard)`, this thus means that you were looking for a way to `generateRow/4` where the initial board and the final board are the *same*, so that would make sure no recursive call could make further "progression" after you generated the `newBoard`.

After all, the `replaceCell` (well given I understood it correctly) changes one cell of the board, and you want to make a recursive call to change cells in the remaining rows.

Most Prolog interpreters will warn you if a variable occurs only once in a clause. For example in SWI Prolog, we get a:

```
Warning: /tmp/pl.pl:6:
    Singleton variables: [New]
```

This thus means that you defined `New` in the head, but never in the body linked it properly. This is at least odd. If you really are not interested in that variable, you typically use an underscore (then the interpreter will not show this error).

Comment: Much thanks, I guess my misunderstanding was that I thought I had to have that parameter be the new board so prolog would know what to assign the final value to? How else does it determine what "New" is if we never tell it New = Newboard? Or does my base case account for that?

Comment: @DevG: no, you define `New` in the head of the predicate, so you link it back with a parameter in the head part of the clause. Each clause has its own scope of variables.